# ¿Cómo cambio el idioma de mi página?

Tags: html, jquery

Tengo ésta página en la que está la letra de una canción y al pasar el mouse por encima de cierta parte de la letra aparece un cuadro con información. Ésto lo hice con jQuery.
El caso es que lo que quiero hacer es que, al seleccionar con botones el idioma español o ingles, esa información del cuadro aparezca en uno u otro idioma.
Sé que con jQuery se puede cambiar un texto de un idioma a otro, pero yo el texto de la pagina (osea la letra de la canción) quiero que quede en su idioma original. Lo único que quiero cambiar es el texto que aparece y desaparece según paso el mouse (el del id="mensaje_frase0").
Alguien me podria explicar cómo hacerlo?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssred.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script>
    
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#mensaje_frase0").hide();
        $("#frase0").hover(mensaje_on0, mensaje_off0);
        
    });

    
    function mensaje_on0(){
        $("#mensaje_frase0").show();    
    }
    
    function mensaje_off0(){
        $("#mensaje_frase0").hide();
    }   
    
</script>

</head>
    
<style> 
    
body
{
    background:url("../imagenes/red/lucky.jpg"); /*La foto*/
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:600px 0%;
        
}   


a{  /* Para sacarle el subrayado y el color azul, así no se ve como un link */
    text-decoration: none;
    color:red;
}

#titulo{
    font-size: 33px;
}


    #mensaje_frase0{
        position: fixed;  /*o absolute?*/
        left: 500px;
        top: 100px;   /*originalmente tenia 392px*/
        width: 315px;
        height: 430px;
        background-color: #D7CFDA;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 25px 15px 15px 500px;
        border: 2px #00F;
        font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
        text-align: center;
    }

    
</style>    

<body>
    
<div id="mensaje_frase0"> "The lucky one" fue elegido por Taylor para ser el track n° 13 por ser éste su número de la suerte (ella nació el 13 de Diciembre de 1989).</div>     
    

<div class="contenido"> 

    <div class="izq">
    
        <div class="home">  
            <button id="HomeButton" onclick="location.href='../index.html';" class="float-left submit-button" >Home!</button>       
        </div>


        <div class=previousnext>    
            <button id="PreviousButton" onclick="location.href='../paginas/sadbeautifultragic.html';" class="float-left submit-button" >←Previous track</button>        
            <button id="NextButton" onclick="location.href='../paginas/everythinghaschanged.html';" class="float-left submit-button" >Next track →</button>     
        </div>  


    <span class="hover_img" id="frase0">
        <a class="titulo" href="#">13. The Lucky One<br></a></span>
    

<div class="song">

<p>New to town with a made up name in the angel's city,<br>
Chasing fortune and fame.<br>
And the camera flashes<br>
Make it look like a dream.</p>
    
<p>You had it figured out since you were in school<br>
Everybody loves pretty, everybody loves cool<br>
So overnight you look like a sixties' queen</p>
    
<p>Another name goes up in lights,<br>
Like diamonds in the sky</p>
    
<p>And they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Yeah, they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
But can you tell me now, you're the lucky one<br>
Oh, oh, oh...</p>
    
<p>Now it's big black cars, and Riviera views<br>
And your lover in the foyer doesn't even know you<br>
And your secrets end up splashed on the news front page</p>
    
<p>And they tell you that you're lucky<br>
But you're so confused,<br>
'Cause you don't feel pretty, you just feel used.<br>
And all the young things line up to take your place</p>
    
<p>Another name goes up in lights<br>
You wonder if you'll make it out alive</p>
    
<p>And they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one.<br>
Yeah, they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one.<br>
Can you tell me now, you're the lucky one<br>
Oh, oh, oh.</p>
    
<p>It was a few years later<br>
I showed up here<br>
And they still tell the legend of how you disappeared<br>
How you took the money and your dignity<br>
And got the hell out<br>
They say you bought a bunch of land somewhere<br>
Chose the Rose Garden over Madison Square<br>
And it took some time, but I understand it now</p>
    
<p>'Cause now my name is up in lights<br>
But I think you got it right,</p>
    
<p>Let me tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Let me tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Let me tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Oh, oh, oh.</p>
    
<p>Yeah they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Yeah, they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
And they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Oh, oh, oh.<br>
Oh, whoa, oh, oh</p>

</div>
<div id="div2">
    &nbsp;
</div>          
</div>  


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una solucion simple, es tener los distintos textos en un array, donde cada posicion corresponda a un idioma.
Con una variable controlas que idioma està seleccionado, y cuando modifiques ese idioma, modificas el contenido con el texto del array que corresponda a la posicion del idioma seleccionado.
Algo parecido a esto:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#mensaje_frase0").hide();
        $("#frase0").hover(mensaje_on0, mensaje_off0);
        eligeIdioma();
    });

    
    function mensaje_on0(){
        $("#mensaje_frase0").show();    
    }
    
    function mensaje_off0(){
        $("#mensaje_frase0").hide();
    }   
    
    /* Idioma */
    var idioma = 0 ; // 0=es, 1=en, ...
    var idiomas=["Español","Inglés"];
    var texto = [   "\"The lucky one\" fue elegido por Taylor para ser el track n° 13 por ser éste su número de la suerte (ella nació el 13 de Diciembre de 1989).",
                    "\"The lucky one\" was chosen by Taylor to be track No. 13 to be his lucky number (he was born on December 13, 1989)."
                ];
    function eligeIdioma(){
        IDidioma.innerHTML=idiomas[idioma];
        mensaje_frase0.innerHTML=texto[idioma];
    }
    function modificaIdioma(){
        idioma++;
        if (idioma < 0 || idioma > 1) idioma = 0;
        eligeIdioma();
    }
```

```css
body
{
    background:url("../imagenes/red/lucky.jpg"); /*La foto*/
    background-repeat:repeat-y;
    background-position:600px 0%;
        
}   


a{  /* Para sacarle el subrayado y el color azul, así no se ve como un link */
    text-decoration: none;
    color:red;
}

#titulo{
    font-size: 33px;
}


    #mensaje_frase0{
        position: fixed;  /*o absolute?*/
        left: 0px;
        top: 100px;   /*originalmente tenia 392px*/
        width: 315px;
        height: 430px;
        background-color: #D7CFDA;
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 25px 15px 15px 500px;
        border: 2px #00F;
        font-family: Segoe, "Segoe UI", "DejaVu Sans", "Trebuchet MS", Verdana, "sans-serif";
        text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sin título</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="cssred.css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    
<div id="mensaje_frase0"></div>     
    

<div class="contenido"> 

    <div class="izq">
    
        <div class="home">  
            <button id="HomeButton" onclick="location.href='../index.html';" class="float-left submit-button" >Home!</button>       
        </div>


        <div class=previousnext>    
            <button id="PreviousButton" onclick="location.href='../paginas/sadbeautifultragic.html';" class="float-left submit-button" >←Previous track</button>        
            <button id="NextButton" onclick="location.href='../paginas/everythinghaschanged.html';" class="float-left submit-button" >Next track →</button>     
        </div>  
        <button id="IDidioma" onclick="modificaIdioma()"></button>

    <span class="hover_img" id="frase0">
        <a class="titulo" href="#">13. The Lucky One<br></a></span>
    

<div class="song">

<p>New to town with a made up name in the angel's city,<br>
Chasing fortune and fame.<br>
And the camera flashes<br>
Make it look like a dream.</p>
    
<p>You had it figured out since you were in school<br>
Everybody loves pretty, everybody loves cool<br>
So overnight you look like a sixties' queen</p>
    
<p>Another name goes up in lights,<br>
Like diamonds in the sky</p>
    
<p>And they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Yeah, they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
But can you tell me now, you're the lucky one<br>
Oh, oh, oh...</p>
    
<p>Now it's big black cars, and Riviera views<br>
And your lover in the foyer doesn't even know you<br>
And your secrets end up splashed on the news front page</p>
    
<p>And they tell you that you're lucky<br>
But you're so confused,<br>
'Cause you don't feel pretty, you just feel used.<br>
And all the young things line up to take your place</p>
    
<p>Another name goes up in lights<br>
You wonder if you'll make it out alive</p>
    
<p>And they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one.<br>
Yeah, they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one.<br>
Can you tell me now, you're the lucky one<br>
Oh, oh, oh.</p>
    
<p>It was a few years later<br>
I showed up here<br>
And they still tell the legend of how you disappeared<br>
How you took the money and your dignity<br>
And got the hell out<br>
They say you bought a bunch of land somewhere<br>
Chose the Rose Garden over Madison Square<br>
And it took some time, but I understand it now</p>
    
<p>'Cause now my name is up in lights<br>
But I think you got it right,</p>
    
<p>Let me tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Let me tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Let me tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Oh, oh, oh.</p>
    
<p>Yeah they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Yeah, they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
And they'll tell you now, you're the lucky one<br>
Oh, oh, oh.<br>
Oh, whoa, oh, oh</p>

</div>
<div id="div2">
    &nbsp;
</div>          
</div>  


</body>
```

Comment: Es perfecto!! justo lo que buscaba, muchisimas gracias!!

Comment: disculpa, ahora estaba intentando aplicar ésto a más de un texto a la vez. (de la misma página),pero la función sólo sirve para uno... traté de volverla a utilizar cambiandole los "frase0" por "frase1" y mensaje_frase0" por "mensaje_frase1" pero no resulta. sabes si es muy difícil hacer que funcione?

Comment: Hola, he respondido en la otra pregunta que has hecho.

Comment: muchisimas gracias otra vez 